# Reading channel locations in MNE Python

Tags: python, eeglab, mne-python

I am new to MNE Python and I am working with .set files from EEGlab(Matlab) for source estimation analysis. The data were recorded from 66 channels (64 EEG and 2 EOG) from EasyCaps, with 10-20 IS. In Matlab, the EEG.chanlocs correctly shows the coordinates of each electrode (labels, type, theta, radius, X, Y, Z, sph_theta, sph_phi, sph_radius, urchin, ref). But it seems that I cannot read these locations in MNE Python.

```
import mne

#The .set files are imported ok
data_path = r"D:\EEGdata";
fname = data_path + '\ppt10.set'
mydata = mne.io.read_epochs_eeglab(fname)

#The data look ok, and channel labels are correctly displayed
mydata
mydata.plot()
mydata.ch_names

#But the channel locations are not found
mydata.plot_sensors()     #RuntimeError: No valid channel positions found
```

Any suggestion on how to read the channel locations from the .set files? Or alternatively, how to manually create the locations based on the coordinates from EEG.chanlocs?

I have also tried to use the default montage 10-20, selecting only the channels I used, but I cannot make it work.

```
#Create a montage based on the standard 1020, which includes 94 electrode labels in upper case
montage = mne.channels.make_standard_montage('standard_1020')
[ch_name.upper() for ch_name in mydata.ch_names] #it correctly convert the channel labels into upper case
mydata.ch_names = [ch_name.upper() for ch_name in mydata.ch_names] #doesn't work
#File "<ipython-input-62-69a7053dc310>", line 1, in <module>
#mydata.ch_names=[ch_name.upper() for ch_name in mydata.ch_names]
#AttributeError: can't set attribute

montage = mne.channels.make_standard_montage('standard_1020',mydata.ch_names]
```

I also thought I could use a conversion tool to convert the .set files into .fif files. I have checked the online documentation, but I cannot find such tool. Any idea?

Comment: Which mne version are you using? Older mne versions did not import channel locations from eeglab files, but newer versions do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I fixed by adding a line for `mydata.set_montage(montage)` before running `mydata.plot_sensors()`. You don't need to convert the channel names to uppercase, as they are case-insensitive in MNE